# Typescript: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature

Tags: typescript, overloading, react-typescript

The following code works if I exclude the `setCurrentTab` from the return interface `useTabsReturnType` but not if I include it and I don't know why

```js
interface useTabsReturnType<T> {
  currentTab: T;
  setCurrentTab: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>;
}

export function useTabs(defaultValues: number): useTabsReturnType<number>;
//This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.ts(2394)
export function useTabs(defaultValues: string): useTabsReturnType<string>;
export function useTabs(defaultValues?: string | number): useTabsReturnType<string | number> {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(defaultValues || '');

  return {
    currentTab,
    setCurrentTab,
  };
}
```

edit: after following Radu Diță's suggestion I got this error:

```
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | number>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> | Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>'.
  Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | number>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>'.
    Type 'SetStateAction<string>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string | number>'.
      Type '(prevState: string) => string' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string | number>'.
        Type '(prevState: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(prevState: string | number) => string | number'.
          Types of parameters 'prevState' and 'prevState' are incompatible.
            Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
              Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
useTabs.ts(20, 3): The expected type comes from property 'setCurrentTab' which is declared here on type 'useTabsReturnType<number> | useTabsReturnType<string>'
```

The error came from here:

```
return {
  currentTab,
  setCurrentTab,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply let your `useTabs` function be generic?

```
export function useTabs<T extends string | number>(defaultValues: T): useTabsReturnType<T> {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(defaultValues);

  return {
    currentTab,
    setCurrentTab,
  };
}
```

Comment: I've not a clue what generics are, but thank you , that seems to work. I'll have to take a look at the docs again

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to change the `return` type for the implementation of the function. Something like this:

```
export function useTabs(defaultValues?: string | number): useTabsReturnType<string> | useTabsReturnType<number> {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(defaultValues || '');

  return {
    currentTab,
    setCurrentTab,
  };
}
```

The important part is this: `useTabsReturnType<string> | useTabsReturnType<number>` instead of `useTabsReturnType<string | number>`

Another solution is to use `type` and allow `TS` to distribute the union. Something like this:

```
type useTabsReturnType<T> = T extends any ? {
  currentTab: T;
  setCurrentTab: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>;
} : never
```

With this change you don't need to change the return type of your function.

Comment: both of your suggestions gave me a new error which I've edited into my original question